# What are good online introductions to testing and Test Driven Development?

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, tdd

I'm looking for an online introduction to unit testing and TDD.  I have virtually no experience with TDD, unit testing, or any other agile methodology.  My development environment is C++ on Linux.  If there's a quality introduction to unit testing and TDD that uses C++ as the example language, that'd be great.  If not then a general introduction in any old language and a more advanced tutorial using C++ would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the introduction to TDD, the [bowling game episode](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/xpepisode.htm) is very nice, as it demonstrate how the tests drive the design. Then, here are tutorials focusing on C++ frameworks for [CppUnit](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-ctools2_cppunit/), [Boot::Test](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-ctools1_boost) and [CppCheck](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-ctools3_ccptest).

To help choosing a framework, Noel LLopis [explored this jungle](http://gamesfromwithin.com/exploring-the-c-unit-testing-framework-jungle), albeit a long time ago, especially it dosen't mention [GoogleTest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) or you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699/choosing-a-c-unit-testing-tool-framework).

Oh, and BTW, [automated] unit testing and TDD can be applied even in non agile environment.

Answer (score 1):

The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) is pretty good and has several useful links to both online and non-online resources of reasonably high quality, including an online tutorial.  Once you have the basics, for C++ specific issues you could start with [this presentation](http://agile2007.agilealliance.org/downloads/presentations/TDD-Cpp-Agile2007-HandsOnTddInCpp.ppt_801.pdf) (PDF).

Comment: That is a link to a powerpoint presentation and not a paper.

Comment: Right -- let me edit the answer to fix the term in question.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a series of blog postings several years ago about how I took some of my 'legacy' code without tests and first added tests to it and then reimplemented it from scratch in a TDD style. The idea was to show TDD and unit testing being used with a non trivial piece of code under test as I'd grown tired of seeing examples of testing simple code.

The code is C++ but it's for Windows so might not interest you, anyway, the articles kick off here: http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2004/05/practical-testing.html